# How do I setup network bond correctly in Lubuntu?

Tags: network-adapter, switch, lubuntu, bonding

In addition to the internal network interface, I added a USB3.0 network controller for testing purposes, will probably be replaced by an internal dual NIC or just another single NIC. I'm running Lubuntu and can't seem to get a network bond working correctly.

I'm trying to use link aggregation with 802.3ad so that both interfaces work at the same time. I got the information mainly from the official [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) and from [this post](https://www.unixmen.com/linux-basics-create-network-bonding-on-ubuntu-14-10/).

Here is the configuration (after loading bonding kernel module)

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enx00e04c20e315
iface enx00e04c20e315 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.1.11
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slaves enp0s31f6 enx00e04c20e315
```

In dmesg I then see

> Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in
>   the bond

Network is still working, but only with one interface. If I check ifconfig, I see both interfaces are listed as SLAVE but only one actually has more than a few KB transferred.
I assume, this is because the switch to which both interfaces are connected to, also needs to be configured correctly, makes sense.

I've got D-Link DGS-1100-08 switches. If I read the specifications correctly, these switches should support 802.3ad. So I configure them through L2 Features -> Link Aggregation -> Enabled and add the two ports to one of the groups.
As soon as I save these settings, network doesn't work at all anymore.

What could be the problem? Did I misunderstand something (bond-mode 4 sould be 802.3ad right? And configuring the switch as I did should enable Lubuntu to communicate with both NICs at the same time, right?)

Answer (score 1):

D-Link support two Bond (Trunk-)Mode: 1-static 2-LACP (=802.3ad, =mode4).
But the small DGS-1100-08 only support static! And not LACP.
ftp://ftp.dlink.de/anleitungen/Switch/Anleitung_Trunking.pdf
(I don't find it in english)

Comment: I don't think the answer is clear .- what is the 2nd mode and how should the OP use it? Please consider adding more details

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, apparently that's correct, 802.3ad is not supported on these switches! TomEus is right though, I don't know exactly how to configure it yet. The German document states, that you need to configure both ends exactly the same way but they don't describe what they understand with "static trunk". Reading up, I acutally think that any of the other modes should work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Tried it out today with bond-mode 0 and it works correctly! Checking with bmon, I can see that traffic is evenly distributed between the two interfaces. If I unplug one of the cables, everything still works. Didn't try all the other modes yet and still don't understand completely how incoming traffic is distributed though.